# Paypal payment pro doesn't work with canadian API Credentials

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement a direct card payment on the site using paypal payments Pro.

I have two test bussiness pro accounts in sandox - **one US and one CA**. When I try to pay to the US account, it works well, but when I try to use API Credentials for the CA account, it returns an error: "**This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.**"

Where is the problem?
Thank you for responses.

Comment: According to [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errors/) it's an invalid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same Pro account on separate PayPal accounts.  Need to get that feature approved and enabled on each account separately.